# how to authenticate from MVC controller into seperate Web Api project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

We are going to build a web project which will potentially use Mobile app as well in the future. So we decide to consume all data works via Web Api. As a start, we will use seperate MVC project. In traditional way, I use Identity2 for authentatication issues and all Controllers of MVC project is secured by [Autherize] attribute. In our scenario, we want to give this job to Web Api project. MVC project will be only consumer of Web Api project. So I am wondering how I can login to Web Api project from MVC project and secure controllers via Web Api. Do you have any suggestions or sample?

Comment: You should be able to use [Authorize] for the web api to if do not am not mistaken.The second thing you will need to do is make sure your API gives tokens to the users that are logged in and use that token to authenticate the user for the remainder of that session. https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/token-based-authentication-web-api/ here you have some more information about the matter.

Comment: Token based authentication via a username and password.

https://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Use authentication scheme such as JWT for easy implementation. For eg. Keycloak provides Oauth authentication and authorization services. And its completely open source.